# How to model payload deployment in General Mission Analysis Tool

Tags: orbital-mechanics, gmat

I just started reading the manuals and doing the tutorials for GMAT. I'd like to use it to model deploying multiple satellites from a launch vehicle and see their resulting orbits. Searching the manual however it's not immediately obvious how one would go about modeling this. Is there a way to "split" a satellite in GMAT? Is there a good example script or paper that describes this process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I've modeled that in the past is to using Python to generate a script with N spacecraft in it, each with their own initial states (chosen from the known distribution), and using a `Propagate Synchronized` statement.

Each phase of the mission would have its own script: upper stage in one script, and use the final state of that propagation statement to build the next script with the N spacecraft.

I hope this helps.

Comment: yes it does, thank you! I'll look into the synchronized trajectory